# Displaying Custom Server Side Error Message in Angular and .Net Core API

Tags: c#, angular, rest, .net-core

I have some rest API written in C# and the API is called from Angular (I am using version Angular 8). The call is fine and it is working fine. However, in case of any exception, I cannot display the customized error message in angular. For example, suppose I have a server side validation in C# which validates if the value of a field matches with the string "abc". If it does not match, it will throw an error and in UI (developed in Angular), I want to display the message

> "Invalid String Specified".

My server side code is as below -

```
if (headerValues.Equals("abc")) {
    throw new InvalidStringException("Invalid String specified", 999);
}
```

The Invalid `InvalidStringException` class is as below -

```
public class InvalidStringException : System.Exception
{
    int status { get; set; }
    public InvalidStringException() { }
    public InvalidStringException(string message, int status) : base(message) {
        this.status = status;
     }
}
```

When that exception is thrown and caught in server side, it is available as 500 exception but could not print the custom message.

I am trying following code in Angular -

```
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error Status: ", error.status);
  console.log("Error Status: ", error.message);
}
```

Please suggest how to handle that scenario.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and looking into the properties that come into the catch block with the error parameter? it may have a different attribute name than simply "status" or "message" what are the attributes and properties for "error" in the catch block?

Comment: What you've got at frontend side? Does catch block catch an error? What object placed in `error`?

Comment: Also try returning the exception instead of throwing maybe?

Comment: Can you show the content of the response for that request in the debugger's network tab?

Comment: Can you show how you call your API from Angular? You only included the `catch` part in the question.

Comment: Can you post more server side code here? For example, how is your exception being converted to a proper HTTP response? And since you are calling from Angular, what CORS setup you have? And in your console, do you see any error like `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`?

Comment: @picolino, yes catch block catch an error and when I print the error it says -                              headers: {…}, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "https://localhost:5001/api/UserDetails/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/UserDetails/: 500 Internal Server Error", error: "InvalidRequestException: Invalid Request\r\n   at abc()  in class :line xx   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )\r\n   at etc etc...                                      My expected error message is Invalid Request

Comment: @ConnorsFan the code to call the API from angular is as below                                                                                           try {
      this.userList = await this.httpClient.get<UserDetails[]>(
              this.myAppUrl + this.myApiUrl, this.httpOptions).toPromise();
      
      return this.userList;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("complete error: ", error);
    }

Comment: @weichch, I have not converted it to any HTTP Response, instead I have thrown the error. Do I need to convert it to HTTP Response? Thanks, I will try it and check if it works. Also I don't have any such error -'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Yes, you need to. See my answer for reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The error object that your Angular app receives should be an instance of `HttpErrorResponse`

You could do something like this to handle http errors:

```js
if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (!error.status) {
    console.log(error.message || error.toString());
  } else {
    console.log(`error status : ${error.status} ${error.statusText}`);
    switch (error.status) {
      case 401:
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
        break;
      case 500:
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");
        console.log(`redirect to login`);
        break;
    }
  }
} else {
  console.error("Other Errors");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you explicitly catching the `InvalidStringException` in your .NET API controller and returning the custom message? If not, the response will be a generic HTTP 500 'Internal Server Error' response. I'd suggest explicitly catching the `InvalidStringException` in your .NET API controller and returning a 400 response with your custom message e.g.

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (InvalidStringException iex) {
    return BadRequest(iex.message); // iex.message == Invalid String specified
}
```

When the `InvalidStringException` scenario occurs, This will return a HTTP 400 response with "Invalid String specified" as the response body. You should be able to log the error on Angular side as you're currently doing...

Comment: Thanks bro...seems it works fine and displaying expected message.

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing an exception which is handled by C# exception handler and it will only return the custom error message specified in that handler.

To return a custom message, you need to return with http code like 4xx or 5xx.

```
new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Custom Message"));
```

Or you can return with 2xx and you have to parse this subscribe or then method e.g.

```
new System.Web.Http.Results.ResponseMessageResult(
                    Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)227, "Custom Error Message")
                );

this.http.get().toPromise().then((response: any) => {
        if (response.status == 227) {
            return error;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
        return apiResponse;
    }).catch(error => {
        //nothing here
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

If throwing a exception is not really necessary, you can return status code 400 and a message using [BadRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

```
if (headerValues.Equals("abc")) {
    return BadRequest("Invalid String specified");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As other people have mentioned, you need to catch the exception and convert it to an appropriate HTTP response in your own code.

The reason for that is because if otherwise your exception is handled by ASP.NET Core using [exception handling configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you have, and it may vary:

#### With developer exception page

Usually in development, you will have code:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

What it does is when your environment is *Development*, it turns on a special page for developers to see information of unhandled exceptions. It is **only** in this case, you get the exception stacktrace as well as the exception message in the response body.

#### Without developer exception page

Conversely, if the exception page is turned off (usually off for *Production* environment), you will see **nothing** in the response body.

#### How to fix

Given exception handling in ASP.NET Core is a cross-cutting concern, I wouldn't use `try...catch` around everywhere `InvalidStringException` needs to be converted to `HttpResponse`.

I would instead use either [an `IActionFilter` or use `UseExceptionHandler` which is the exception handling middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-exceptions-to-modify-the-response):

Here is an example of using `UseExceptionHandler` in `Configure` method in *Startup.cs*:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(opt => opt.Run(
    async ctx =>
    {
        var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (feature.Error is InvalidStringException ex)
        {
            await ctx.Response.WriteAsync(ex.Message);
        }
    }));
```

In this way, your `InvalidStringException` is handled globally in your application, without explicit `try...catch`. And you could throw the exception anywhere in your code, the above code would catch the exception and properly convert it to an HTTP response with your own message as the body.

Also note, because you are calling the API from an Angular app, so chances are  you might need to [set CORS up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in your API application if the two applications run from different origins.

Without CORS, your HTTP request from the Angular app may fail before it can reach your API. In this case, the status of the HTTP response in your Angular app may be `undefined`. And in your console, you could see CORS errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can use http interceptor to create general error handler for all http error in angular app,this way you can use alert ,redirect to login page in case token expired ,overwrite the error object and more  but you can still access to the error object at the component level by add a callback for observable error.

*Error Handler Service*

```js
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private msgServ: MessageService) {}
  public intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        switch (err.status) {
          case 500: {
            this.msgServ.add({
              severity: "error",
              summary: "Error ",
              detail: "Server is gone.."
            });

            break;
          }
          case 400: {
            this.msgServ.add({
              severity: "error",
              summary: "Error ",
              detail: "custome error message..."
            });

            break;
          }
          case 401: {
            if (err.message == "invalid_token") {
              // router  navigate to login
            }
            break;
          }

          default: {
            this.msgServ.add({
              severity: "error",
              summary: "Error ",
              detail: err.message
            });
          }
        }

        return throwError(err);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

add the Interceptor to Providers in app module

```js
@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorHandlerService, multi: true },
    MessageService
  ],
  ....
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-error-handler)

> `MessageService` is related  to primeng component library ,you can use your own alert structure

Comment: I 'm not familiar with don net so my answer ment for the frontend part 